# How can I disable logs being created in standalone python script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, standalone

When I run the following script in QGIS 2.6.1, it produces a folder called 'processing', which contains a log, in the directory it reads files from. And since the script reads files from several locations, there's going to be 'processing' folders scattered around.

Is there a way to disable this?

I've excluded the processes in the script as I believe this is the cause:

```
from processing.ProcessingPlugin import ProcessingPlugin
plugin = ProcessingPlugin(iface)
from processing.tools import *
```

---

Here is the script:

```
import os, sys, glob

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

QgsApplication( [], False, home + "\AppData\Local\Temp" ) # Set a custom config path

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QApplication([])

#Run processes
def run():
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect generated folder/files to a temporal directory of your operating system, so that they don't bother you anymore.

For instance, in GNU/Linux I can use `/tmp` to store all those logs and directories.

You would need to change a part of your script (where you create `QApplication` and set `QgsApplication` properties), like this:

```
QgsApplication( [], False, "/tmp" ) # Set a custom config path
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath( "/usr", True )
QgsApplication.initQgis()

app = QApplication( [] )
```

Comment: Huh interesting...will give that a go and report back.